# Could not connect: Access denied for user

Tags: php, joomla2.5

My site is http://www.bathpass.co.uk/ is in joomla. Here i have an issue when you click on "ROUTE IDEADS". It will point to another domain -  http://www.freedom2explore.co.uk/route_ideas/ .This is beacuse, this menu item is used by external link. The problem is when i changed this above url into this http://www.bathpass.co.uk/route_ideas/. i got this error :

`Could not connect: Access denied for user 'freedom2_sajids3'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

I am accepting your valuable reply.

Thanks

Comment: are you running a site clone on different url?

Comment: The question does not show any kind of research work. Have you even checked mysql docs or even googled the error?

Answer (score 1):

The valuable reply: your login and/or password is wrong.

PS: please don't start arguing - if mysql responds you with "access denied" - it means the credentials are wrong. That simple.

Comment: if you give more information about this error. Means how to fix

Answer (score 0):

your Joomla database configuration in `configuration.php` are set to connect to `localhost` and it's possible your credentials are not good.

however, if you are simply running a website clone on different url (sharing same db), make sure that mysql server & user allow connections from external sources.

For this you will have to:

1. make sure db/firewall allows connection from external servers
2. make sure user access is set to certain domains or `%`
3. Change host in `configuration.php` from localhost to db server's IP address